# Using Scrapy to crawl all pages that are linked to a website with any depth we want

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am interested to know if it is possible to crawl all pages and links on a website with any amount of depth even if after following a few links the top URL changes? Here is an example:

Top URL: www.topURL.com
has 3 links: www.topURL.com/link1, www.topURL.com/link2 and www.topURL.com/link3

Then if we click on www.topURL.com/link1 it takes us to a page that itself has
2 links on it: www.topURL.com/link4 and www.topURL.com/link5

but if we click on www.topURL.com/link4 it takes us to a page that has the following 2 links: www.anotherURL.com/link1 and www.thirdURL.com/link1

Can scrapy, or any python crawler/spider start from www.topURL.com and then follows links and end up on www.thirdURL.com/link1?

Is there a limit on how deep it can go?
Is there any code example to show me how to do it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at scrapy's [`CrawlSpider` spider class](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.9/topics/spiders.html?highlight=CrawlSpider#crawlspider)

> CrawlSpider is the most commonly used spider for crawling regular websites, as it provides a convenient mechanism for following links by defining a set of rules.

To accomplish your goal you'd simply have to set very basic rules:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        # Extract and follow all links!
        Rule(LinkExtractor(callback='parse_item'), follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('crawling'.format(response.url))
```

The crawler above will crawl every url that matches the allowed_domains on the website and callback to `parse_item`.
It should be noted that by default `LinkeExtractor` ignores media pages (like pdf, mp4 etc.)

To expand on depth subjects, scrapy does have DEPTH restriction settings but defaults are set to 0 (aka infinite depth)
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.9/topics/settings.html#depth-limit

```
# settings.py
DEPTH_LIMIT = 0
```

Also scrapy by default crawls depth first but if you want faster coverage breadth first might improve that: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.9/topics/settings.html#depth-limit

```
# settings.py
SCHEDULER_ORDER = 'BFO'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will this also find links that are not on `allowed_domains`? For example as I explained if my allowed_domains is www.topURL.com can the code find the www.thirdURL.com/link1 and then looks there and find list of all links there?

Comment: Nope, but you can just remove allowed domains or add topURL and thirdURL there.

Comment: So if I remove allowed domains then there will not be any restriction? How do I specify the starting URL in that case?

Comment: yes if you remove `allowed_domains` all domains will be allowed. You specify starting urls with `start_urls` class variable :)